# Two mouse pointers with one mouse Win7/8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, mouse

Hi guys i am doing some tests and i would like to have 2 mouse pointers on the screen and just one mouse. My aim is to just click on one location and the other pointer will also click at the same time, nothing fancy needed its just for clicking e.g. both pointers click send at the same time, want to see will they both register or will one give an error, Sorry just trying experiments with race conditions, thanks for any help.
Edit: Sorry forgot to say that what i am talking about is 2 different windows of say the same application. with mouse pointer 1 pointing at lets say send on window 1 and mouse pointer 2 at send on window 2 and the 2 pointers firing at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Messages, such as clicks, are queued. It is not possible to send multiple messages at the same time. You can only send one right after the other. That can be done by firing a mouse click event from your current event handler. You should also know that how this is done is completely language dependent.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me on this, i will look more into event handler end of things. Any additional info would be greatly appreciated, thanks again